# Arduino PROGMEM byte array

Tags: arrays, arduino

Consider this snippet, compiled with Arduino IDE:

```
PROGMEM  char charSet[]  = { 0x0, 0x8, 0x4, 0xc, 0x2, 0xA , 0x6, 0xE, 0x1, 0x9,0x5, 0xD, 0x3,0xB,0x7,0xF };
char reversed[]          = { 0x0, 0x8, 0x4, 0xc, 0x2, 0xA , 0x6, 0xE, 0x1, 0x9,0x5, 0xD, 0x3,0xB,0x7,0xF };
char ff;

for (int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(reversed[i], HEX);
}

Serial.println(" ");
for (int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print(" ");
    ff = pgm_read_byte(&charSet[i]);
    Serial.print(ff);
}
```

I would expect the two for loops to produce same output. But the output is:

```
  0 8 4 C 2 A 6 E 1 9 5 D 3 B 7 F
  FFFFFF94 FFFFFFB0 6 FFFFFF80 FFFFFF91 FFFFFFC7 3 62 FFFFFFE3 E FFFFFF94 5E 29 FFFFFF99 23 39
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer was the PROGMEM declaration. I had to move it out from function, adding `const` keyword. Other changes as datatypes were not working.

The full answer is on [Arduino forum](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,120603.0.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `const` keyword is missing.

Probably it is not a good idea to use `prog_char`, as it is marked as *deprecated* in gcc-avr, see [avr/pgmspace.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#gaa475b6b81fd8b34de45695da1da523b6)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong datatype. From http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM:

> Some cryptic bugs are generated by using ordinary datatypes for program memory calls.

You can't use `char` — you have to use `prog_char`

So:

```
PROGMEM prog_char charSet[] = {0x0, 0xB}
```

That should work.

by the way: You don't have to do `Serial.println(" ");`  You can just do `Serial.println();`

Answer (score 0):

```
PROGMEM  char charSet[] = ...
```

This is not good - for PROGMEM data, you can't use ordinary in-memory types. What you should do is

```
PROGMEM  prog_char charSet[] = ...
```